# how to determine max peak of switching regulator in frequency domain (radiated emission)

Tags: emc, switching-regulator, spectrum-analyzer

I want to know how do I determine what should be the switching regulator peak in frequency domain(Radiated emission) , and where should I measure (Output or on inductor , capacitor).

Lets do below example which I am working on: [LM34936EVM](https://www.ti.com/tool/LM34936EVM) which has switching freq of 300khz and out of 12V

Below is near filed snap shot using 20mm H field probe on top of inductor. I am using Rigol DSA815 which I am not very familiar with. (please let me know if I have to change setting or if you want more data with finer loop)

[image]

I want to know if this switching regulator is normal or not.

Comment: Is this for a certification? Radiated usually means measuring with an antenna.

Comment: @Voltage Spike No, what I meant radiated emissions of switching regulator.

Comment: There is no such thing as normal when it comes to switching regulator so, what is it that you *really* want to know?

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'd expect to see sampling the magnetic field around the inductor: fundamental at the switching frequency with odd harmonics. Are you expecting to see something different? Compliance cares about far-field radiated emissions, not near-field, so while those little E-field/H-field probes are super handy for sniffing out problems they really don't let you know if you'll pass or fail. You need to get into an anechoic chamber for that...

Comment: I would like to know where  -29dbm came from and how do you calculate.

Comment: @peter  I totally agree this does not tell me if I pass or not, but there should be way I can determine what should be max amplitude with certain current, if not then I understand.

Comment: Check the documentation that came with the probe... it should specify the sensitivity. If it gives it to you in voltage output for a given A/m field strength you'll have to convert, keeping in mind your SA has a 50 ohm input. But again, what are you hoping to look at here? This is a near-field measurement, and EMC cares about far-field.

Comment: @Peter Thanks you kind of answer my question. I am trying to see when I choose switching regulator controller  how do I determine which have the least EMI, since I have some sensitive sensors that change value when it goes next to magnetic field.

Comment: The controller's importance in generating EMI is secondary to the type of inductor you are using and measuring and the type of filtering around the controller. The near-field probe is not telling you anything without knowledge of the near-field probe and how close to the inductor you are. Then it's a guessing game.

Comment: @Andyaka basically if you do not have correct information about your probe all result does not mean any thing, thanks I didn't know that.

Comment: If you have parts that are sensitive to the magnetic field of the inductor, then you may need to change the shape of your inductor in order to have its field not interfere with other parts. Torriods are usually selected for this reason.  However they are not perfect.

Comment: This introduction to radiated emission testing principles probably gives an idea what's needed to get some actual info: https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/files/d-i-y_emc_testing_2001_part_1_radiated_emissions.pdf If you have a critical application learn the EMC standards for that application. You can buy high cost certified power supplies which can be used for ex. in aeroplanes, in merchant vessel bridge equipment, in hospitals etc... If one orders something from foreign webshops  it can be difficult to make difference between a real thing and a counterfeit which surely has all the needed stamps.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for the document, I will go head and review it.